# Deleting a host-only cookie via javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Came across this particular predicament today, wanted to delete a hostOnly cookie using the good old - 'set a past date as expires' trick.

But come what may, I was not able to delete a hostOnly cookie even by setting the expiry date to 2000.

A small code snippet.

```
var somePast = new Date(2000,03);
document.cookie="TARGET_COOKIE=asda; path=/ ;domain=subdomain.domain.com; expires="+today
```

And Voila!, the cookie was still there.

On searching, came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482743/why-cant-i-expire-a-cookie-with-javascript-not-httponly), and the second answer said "If you have a hostOnly cookie, do not specify the domain when you modify/expire it."

and changing the code snippet as below

```
   document.cookie ="TARGET_COOKIE=asda; path=/ ;expires="+today
```

It worked like a charm, bye-bye hostOnly cookies!

- Why does this happen?
- I tried the same with `hostOnly: false` cookies, but they weren't deleted, they required a domain to be set.  What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you have to write the exact same params to delete it (or edit) as when you created it.